# Tiles reloading Left menu using Struts 1.3

Tags: tiles, struts-1

I am using struts 1.3 and tiles to develop web application,it is reloading leftmenu even after using tiles.can anyone please give some idea

Answer (score 0):

Tiles won't help you if you want to reload some part of page only as purpose of tiles is to reuse across the presentation tier of an application.

you need to either use frames or dhtml layers to refresh part of a 'page'.

Angular.js is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tiles, it is bound to reload the page because tiles only works when the request is sent and the response comes from controller.
The way by which you can avoid reloading of menu in struts 1.x,2 is :-
 1. You can use AJAX or a DWR calls to get the response.
 2. Or you can use frameset to give the response.